# An issue while creating multiple unique columns with GORM

Tags: sql, hibernate, grails-orm

I have this Grails domain class:

```
class MyClass {

    static auditable = true;

    String description;
    Boolean isActive=true;
    Date deletedAt;


    static constraints = {
        description size: 1..250, blank: false, unique:['deletedAt', 'isActive'], index:'myclass_idx'
        deletedAt nullable: true, index:'myclass_idx'
        isActive index:'myclass_idx'
    }
}
```

What I expect it to do is to create a constraint which won't allow duplicate records like these:

```
id| description | is_active | deleted_at  
1 | desc1       | true      | (null)
2 | desc1       | true      | (null)
```

but this stil happens. What am I missing here?

**UPD:** figured out that this happens only when there are null values compared to each other. If `deleted_at` contains two equal date values, the constraint works.

Is there a workaround for that?

Answer (score 0):

Finally decided to use default not-null values for `deletedAt` field.