# MySQL: How to ensure unique constraint on multiple fields works with NULL values?

Tags: mysql

This is like part2 of this question: [An issue while creating multiple unique columns with GORM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15218062)

I have created a table with a *unique* constraint on a number of fields (description, is_active, deleted_at). It turned ot that it works with such rows:

```
id| description | is_active | deleted_at  
1 | desc1       | true      | 01/01/2000
2 | desc1       | true      | 01/01/2000
```

and doesn't work like this:

```
id| description | is_active | deleted_at  
1 | desc1       | true      | NULL
2 | desc1       | true      | NULL
```

and I don't want rows with NULL values to be duplicated as well. Is there a workaround for that?

Comment: possible duplicate of [An issue while creating multiple unique columns with GORM](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15218062/an-issue-while-creating-multiple-unique-columns-with-gorm)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> **[13.1.14. CREATE TABLE
> Syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/create-table.html)**
>
> A
> UNIQUE index creates a constraint such that all values in the index
> must be distinct. An error occurs if you try to add a new row with a
> key value that matches an existing row. **For all engines, a UNIQUE
> index allows multiple NULL values for columns that can contain NULL.**

As a workaround you can try to make `deleted_at` column not nullable with default value 0

```
deleted_at NOT NULL DEFAULT 0
```

And build your queries and app logic around that.

Another option would be to enforce this constraint with a trigger.

Comment: Yes, I finally decided to use not-null values as default. Thanks.